# How to load init.sql file to postgres service in gitlab ci?

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to init my `service` in the test stage using a `sql` file.

```
test:
  services:
    - postgres:latest
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: test
  stage: test
  image: gliderlabs/herokuish:latest
  script:
    - setup_test_db
    - cp -R . /tmp/app
    - /bin/herokuish buildpack test
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    variables:
      - $TEST_DISABLED
```

This is the test job as in `auto devops`.
I want to use the postgres image `docker-entrypoint`.
This is how I use it in `docker-compose` on my pc:

```
volumes:
  - './src/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d'
```

This way, when the `postres` image starts up, I have my schema ready to use.
How can I manage to do it in `gitlab-ci.yml`?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment `volumes` is not supported in Gitlab CI.

A workaround solution for this during your test you use `docker-compose` which has a service for `postgres` to spin up your project and you can mount it volume as normal

Answer (score 1):

You can added below script into your gitlab ci to make it work.

```
before_script:
  - apt update && apt install -y postgresql
  - export PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  - psql -h "postgres" -U "$POSTGRES_USER" -d "$POSTGRES_DB" -f ./src/sql
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a simple SQL fixture (such as adding a USER) You could override `command` in your service definition to inject your SQL into the service container's `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

```
test:
  services:
    - postgres:latest
      command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - >-
          echo "$SOME_SQL" > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql &&
          docker-entrypoint.sh # or whatever is called in that image
  script:
    - ...
```

And in case you are wondering, no... there is no way to populate the $SOME_SQL variable with a file in your repository. So this is only a viable workaround if you can get away with an inline variable in this YAML, CI variable from the Gitlab UI, etc.